# rspec assertions on new window

Tags: browser, rspec, watir-webdriver, assertions

I'm using watir-webdriver and rspec to write assertions.  I am running into some problems running assertions on elements of a new window. 
This is my method I am using:

```
def open_window
    foobar = @browser.window(:title, 'Foo View')
    return foobar
end
```

This is how I am writing my spec:

```
describe 'testing a new window' do
    it 'opens a new window' do
        open_window.use
        sleep 2 # hackey way of getting it to work so far
    end
    it 'sees elements on page' do
        # code for expectations of elements
        # Several more it blocks
    end
end
```

What is happening:
Unless I put in a `sleep` command for an indeterminate amount of time, it seems like the window closes before it can run through all the assertions.  Is there some kind of a `wait` that can be applied to keep the new window open through the entire spec?

Comment: Your web application is opening a browser and then closing it after a short period of time? And you want to execute all of your tests before it closes?

Comment: @titusfortner, yes--I am looking for it to run the assertions on the window that it opens

Comment: @kmancusi, who is closing the new window? Is it the application you are testing or are you telling Watir to close it? It would be pretty unusual for Watir to randomly close the window. Are you sure one of your tests isn't causing the closure? Is it always the same set of tests that pass before the window closes?

Comment: Yeah, if your app is closing the window, there isn't much you can do about it in your test. If it is taking a certain amount of time to open, you can use `#when_present` when switching to the window, or on the element after switching to the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some refactoring and it is working properly now--essentially it was a matter of setting to say something along the lines of `#when_present.use`

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet.

When the window is available, assuming you're not performing actions on the page, just push all the content into an instance variable before it closes and then run your assertions against that?

Not ideal, but it might work.